# How to Update n number of PFObjects with single PFQuery in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using Parse.com in IOS Application. In that i am using one Class Background which contains another Class values as row like an array.
 I want to update an array of those values without using for loop. I want to update with only one Single PFQuery Call.

**Class**

**Image** -- id   - image (**PFFile**)  - count (**integer**)

**Background** -- id - imagesArr (**Array**)

The Background class contains image ids in imagesArr. I want to update one row in background. Then i need to update all  images whose are imagesArr increment their count column in Image Class.

We can do it by using for loop.

like

```
[bgQuery findObjectinBackground:^(NSArray * imageIds, NSError *error)
{
  if(!error)
   {
     for(int i= 0; i<imageIds.count; i++)
    {
    NSString *imageId = [imagesIds objectAtIndex:i];
    PFQuery *getImageQuery = [PFquery queryWithClassName:@"Image"];
     [getImageQuery getObjectWithIdInBackground:imageId withBlock]
// Code for refresh

     } 
   } 
}
```

We can do it like by using for . But i need to execute n number of PFQueries. I felt it leads to slow the application Performance.

Instead of this can we update all images in Background row imagesArr id with one single PFQuery.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Did you try `saveAll` or `saveAllInBackground` ? It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. NOTE: You don't need to query the for the PFObject if know that objectId and you are sure the object is existing on the server.

Comment: Thanks for response
I never tried saveAll till now. I will review it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing because you keep saying that you are updating with a query.  Queries are for retrieving objects.

With that being said, nested objects save automatically.  For example

```
PFObject * object1 = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Object1"];
PFObject * object2 = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Object2"];

object1[@"object2ref"] = object2;

[object1 save]; // this should save object 2 as well.
```

If you do this several times and have an array of Object1's

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:arrayOfObject1objects]; // will save all object 1's, and object 2's
```

In retrieving objects.

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Object1];
[query includeKey:@"object2Ref"]

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // all objects, and object2ref data should be available
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error, %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.